# "Free" array element in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, free, shift

I have an object array

```
Timed_packet* send_queue = new Timed_packet[num_sequence_numbers]; // size=10
```

That will be filled with Timed_packets at one point,
Is there any one of deleting or freeing the elements in there and then shift the array to the left to replace what have been freed?

Example

```
send_queue = [ packet 9, packet 8, packet 7, packet 6, packet 5, packet 4, packet 3, packet 2, packet 1, packet 0]
```

and I wanted to delete packet 5 and everything to its left, making send_queue look like

```
send_queue = [ packet 4, packet 3, packet 2, packet 1, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty, empty]
```

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't implement this by deleting or freeing the elements, because you've allocated an array as a single memory region.  The region can only be freed as a whole, not in parts.

As others have mentioned though, you can use a variety of techniques to "virtualize" the array and make it look like elements are coming and going:

```
packet *queue = new packet[queue_capacity];
packet *begin = queue, *end = queue+queue_capacity, *first = queue, *last = queue;

// add an element to the queue
packet p(...);
*last++ = *p; // note postincrement
if (last == end) last = begin; // the queue is cyclic
if (last == first) throw new queue_overflow(); // ran out of room in the queue!

// remove an element from the queue
if (first==last) throw new queue_underflow(); // ran out of items in the queue!
packet p = *first++; // taken by copy; note postincrement
if (first == end) first = begin; // the queue is still cyclic
```

This code is off of the top of my head.  You might need to fix a couple boundary conditions but the theory is there.

This is essentially what you'd be getting if you used std::deque, except the latter offers:

- performance
- portability
- type safety
- boundary safety
- standards compliance

*EDIT:* One thing you could do to improve this is to allocate an array of pointers (packet**), instead of an array of values (packet*).  Then your enqueue/dequeue operations are copies of pointers to packets, instead of copies of packets.  You'd need to make sure packets were freed by the dequeuer, and not by the enqueuer, but this should be lightyears faster (sic).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can manually write a loop to move everything to the left and fill in the remaining elements with an "empty" value (perhaps `nullptr`, or `NULL` if you're not using C++11).

Comment: No worries, use `NULL` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way to implement this, is to implement it literally: shift the data in the array by copying "packet 4" to the beginning of the array, "packet 3" to the next element and so on. Fill the unused rest of the array with whatever element value stands for "empty" in your case.

Remember that C++ has no built-in concept of an "empty" element of an array. You will either have to implement it manually by creating some reserved state of your `Timed_packet` object that stands for an "empty" packet. Or, alternatively, you can simply remember that your array contains only 4 elements now and the rest is assumed "empty" regardless of the state.